# How do I flush extraneous characters from cin?

Tags: c++, iostream

```
char buff[3];

cout<<"From: ";
cin.getline(buff, 3);

//something something

cout<<"To: ";
cin.getline(buff, 3);
```

How can I clear buffer at comment so extra chars don't go to my second `cin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `istream::ignore`:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This will skip the maximum possible number of characters up until a newline is read.

For what it's worth, though, you should probably not be using `istream::getline`, as it works with raw C-style strings.  A better option would be to use `std::string` and the free function `std::getline`:

```
std::string buffer;
getline(cin, buffer);
```

This will automatically read all the characters from `stdin` up until a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [istream::ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#import<string.h>

memset(buf, 0, 3);
```

This will fill the buffer with zeros.

Comment: That clears the memory buffer. He's talking about the input buffer.

Comment: @Steven : Then his choice in variable names is confusing at best. ;-]